# Entity returns same registry for all rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity

I'm trying to get all rows from a table using the following:

```
using (var context = new dbcontext()){

return context.table.ToList();
}
```

my problem is: this command returns 1232 registry (count on table) with the same data in all rows, even if I exec a `.Distinct();`
PS: I have 1232 different registries

Comment: We would have to see a snapshot of the data in the table.

Comment: Need more info to help you out. Your posted code seems fine there must be an error somewhere else. What DB? What does the Table on SQL Server look like? What data can you see with a SQL Tool (like SSMS)? Whats the connectionstring?

Comment: If you are not able to provide information about the database, you can enable database query logging and log to Debug trace `Database.Log = (query) => Debug.Write(query);`. This will help you figure out the actual query running against database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this entity have an ID column? If so, then all rows will always be different, since the ID's are unique.

You should select the relevant columns (excluding the ID column at least) in an anonymous, and THEN do the .Distinct().

Comment: my table doesn't has a id Column, after define an ID column, the problem was solved. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I am glad you solved the problem... but I don't think my answer should be the answer though. Anyways, glad I got you on the right track by accident.